# What is the infinite series of $\tan( z) $?

Tags: complex-analysis

My teacher showed me how to do it and I've since forgotten how. The notes I had have vanished! Was wondering if anyone could show me how to do it step-by-step? I know I have to equate coefficients, but I just keep confusing myself...

Comment: Do you mean $\tan$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are familiar with Taylor Theorem, you have from Taylor theorem that, the infinite series of a function about a point is given by:
$$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{f^n(a)}{n!}(x-a)^n$$ or
$$f(x)=f(a)+\frac{f'(a)}{1!}(x-a)+\frac{f''(a)}{2!}(x-a)^2+\frac{f'''(a)}{3!}(x-a)^3+\dots$$

You can compute the series term by term, by evaluating the derivative for each n. About the origin i.e. $a=0$, you get,
$$\tan(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{B_{2n}(-4)^n(1-4^n)}{2n!}x^{2n-1}$$ $$=x+\frac{x^3}{3}+\frac{2x^5}{15}+\frac{17x^7}{315}+\frac{62x^9}{2835}+\frac{1382x^{11}}{155925} \dots$$
Where $B_{2n}$ Refer to [Even Indexed Bernouli Numbers](http://oeis.org/wiki/Bernoulli_numbers)

For details see [Taylor Series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series).

Comment: Oh wow. -_- Equating coefficients is a much more tedious method. Thank you, good sir.